# Call function directly after constructor: new Object()->callFunction()

Tags: php, function, class, constructor, call

As you might have seen in the title, my programming background is Java. In Java you can do stuff like this

```
new Object().callSomeMethod();
```

without assigning the created Object to a variable, very useful and clear coding if you only need this Object once.

Now in PHP i try to do the same

```
new Object()->callSomeMethod();
```

but here i get a 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)'.

**Is there a way to do this in PHP ?**

Comment: Only in PHP >= 5.4 e.g. `echo (new DateTime())->format('d-M-Y');`

Comment: Declare the method static?
`Object::callSomeMethod();`

Comment: @MarkBaker Nope. I've seen in 5.4

Comment: Static is not an option, it has to be an object :) @MarkBaker Thanks, this is what i searched for

Comment: @Basti - accept Kita's answer then, as he's given the correct solution

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
(new Object())->callSomeMethod();
```

will work in PHP 5.4+

**EDIT**

It is a [new feature](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) added on PHP 5.4:

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. `(new Foo)->bar()`.

**EDIT2**

The [PHP feature RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/instance-method-call) proposes two sets of syntax(with & without brackets), both of them are implemented in the RFC, but only one has been shipped. I couldn't find links explaining the decision.

Let's take a look at the bracketless syntax examples in the RFC:

- `new foo->bar()` should be read as `(new foo)->bar()`
- `new $foo()->bar` should be read as `(new $foo())->bar`
- **`new $bar->y()->x`** should be read as **`(new ($bar->y)())->x`**

I think bracketless syntax is not shipped because its proposed parsing precedence is not very intuitive(hard to follow by eyes) as shown in the 3rd example.

Comment: Why does PHP not allow the syntax as mentioned by OP?

Comment: Can you include information about why the parentheses are neccessary? According to the operator precedence list, `new` has highest precedence, but `->` occurs nowhere in this list...

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address my question why the parens are neccessary.