# Is it possible to use new object directly? i.e. "new foo()->zork()"

Tags: php, syntax, constructor

I have a PHP class with a member returning an assoative array.
I may do

```
$bar = new foo();
$something = $bar->zork();
```

and $Something contains what I expect.

If I do

```
$something = new foo()->zork();
```

I get an error: unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR.

Can this construction, that is very common in Java, be done in PHP?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188629/php-how-to-chain-method-on-a-newly-created-object?rq=1 (however the accepted answer does not cover the syntax noted by Mark Baker and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16296437/2864740), which is PHP 5.4+)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873341/call-function-directly-after-constructor-new-object-callfunction?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

It is allowed, but use

```
$something = (new foo())->zork();
```

The extra brackets are essential

And I believe this syntax was only introduced in PHP 5.4.0, so you'd still get an error with earlier versions of PHP