# Error appears in Facebook sdk library file

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I just started working with Facebook sdk and I am following the [packet code example.](https://github.com/packetcode/fblogin-basic) But when I start running it, it gave me many errors but was able to fix them by referring to [this](http://netization.blogspot.com/2014/09/create-facebook-login-for-website-using.html), but this I couldn't fix this error:

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.RuntimeException: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in C:\Users\HP USER\Downloads\Apache Tomcat \GraphSessionInfo.php on line 90
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in \GraphSessionInfo.php on line 90

Error refered to the below code

```
public function getIssuedAt()
{
    $stamp = $this->getProperty('issued_at');
    if ($stamp) {
        return (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp($stamp);  **//line 90**
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling class methods directly after instantiation (sth. like `(new \DateTime())->setTimestamp(...)`) was [added in PHP 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873341/call-function-directly-after-constructor-new-object-callfunction) and was **not supported in prior versions** (also see the [official documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)).

When you are using an older PHP version (probably 5.3 from the looks of it), you will need to **store the constructor result in a variable** before calling additional methods on that object:

```
$datetime = new \DateTime();
return $datetime->setTimestamp($tstamp);
```

You should also consider that PHP 5.3 has reached it's end-of-life in [August 2014](http://php.net/eol.php) and is not supported anymore. Consider upgrading to a newer version (since you appear to be running PHP in a Java servlet container, this might not be trivial, though).